# ui-grid filtering and selection does not work when using both

Tags: angular-ui-grid

filtering does not work in ui-grid when selection is on , but when i remove ui-grid-selection directive from html part the filtering works well !!!
notes: I fill columnDefs of gridOptions later dynamically through a service call .

.js code :

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {             
         ,enableRowSelection: true
         , enableRowHeaderSelection: true
         , multiSelect: false
         , treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible: false
         , useExternalFiltering: true

         , onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
             self.gridApi = gridApi;

             gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, function () {

                 if (!usePagination)
                     return;

                 var grid = this.grid;
                 var gridfilter = [];

                 angular.forEach(grid.columns, function (col, index) {
                     if (col.filters[0].term)

                         gridfilter.push(
                                {
                                    FieldName: col.name,
                                    MatchType: 6,
                                    Value1: col.filters[0].term
                                }
                         );
                 });

                 self.searchOption.filters = [{ filter: gridfilter }];
                 self.reload();
             });
 }
```

.html code:

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" dir="rtl" style="height: 600px; width: 100%" 
                     ui-grid-selection></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i initiated columnDefs in gridOption and it solved the problem:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
         columnDefs:[{}]
         ,enableRowSelection: true
         ....
}
```